# Uninstall owncloud desktop 2.6.3.14058 impossible

Tags: owncloud

I have tried to uninstall *OwnCloud Desktop*. However the uninstaller can‘t locate the original installer in `C:\Users\\****\AppData\Roaming\ownCloud\`. The old installer is no longer available on the *OwnCloud* website. Updating first won't work since the program first tries to uninstall the old version and I end up in a cycle. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter link description here][1]

There are several methods on this webpage, I would suggest you try method 3 as you don't have an uninstaller and can't even update.
[1]: http://www.uninstallhelps.com/how-to-uninstall-owncloud2.html